# How to get mod to print as a percent in excel 2013?

Tags: excel

I'm currently making a spreadsheet and in my spreadsheet I have 8 different numbers going across a row and the last number being the total of the numbers. So for example:

```
                                                              Total
1     2       3        4         5      6        7       8       36
```

I'm trying to use the MOD function to give me the remainder of each number divided by the total but instead its giving me not what I want. So for example 2/36 = .055555 repeating but instead its giving me only 2. Any help? Also how can I get it to return as a percent? So it would actually be 5.5%? Never really used excel a lot. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Format cell as a percent with 1 decimal?

Comment: It sounds like MOD is doing what it's supposed to, and what you're explicitly asking for-- finding the remainder.  If you're really after the percentage of the total do what findwindow said.

Comment: I found the decimal format but is MOD a bad function to use for this situation?

Comment: it does exactly what it should to.... `x mod y` is like doing `x - y` as long as `x >=y` and then return x.... if you want to get 0.0555 -> `x / y` and format the chell as percentage

Comment: For the displaying as percentage part, use ToString("P");

Comment: Ok. Thanks Dirk. I thought MOD would return the answer as a decimal. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your words describe MOD (ie remainder post division) but the example you have given is a straight divide.

Here are both of those as formulas:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       36
0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   2.78%   0.00%   2.78%   11.11%
2.78%   5.56%   8.33%   11.11%  13.89%  16.67%  19.44%  22.22%
```

First line is your numbers, second is using MOD, third is using straight divide:

Enter this in A2 and drag across `=MOD($I$1,A$1)/$I$1`

Enter this in A3 and drag across `=A1/$I$1`

Format as % to 2dp